# How to organize data in Nunjucks working with 11ty?

Tags: javascript, templating, static-site, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm developing a static site using 11ty with Nunjucks. It's for a company that provides training for certification exams (AWS etc.) and they have ~25 Certification Training Courses each having its own data.

I have made it work but I have a strong feeling that there's a simpler and convenient way to organize this data. The data is something like this for each course:

```
Title:
Subtext:
Date:
Duration:
```

So far, so good. The tricky part is the course syllabus. It is organized something like this:

```
1. Topic Title
    1.1 Subtopic Title
    1.1 Subtopic Description
    1.2 Subtopic Title
    1.2 Subtopic Description

2. Topic Title
    2.1 Subtopic Title
    2.1 Subtopic Description
    2.2 Subtopic Title
    2.2 Subtopic Description
```

Around 4-8 topics for each course. I am currently denoting each of these variables with their standalone names which is making this very messy.

```
agenda_1: 
a1_1: 
a1_1_text: 
a1_2: 
a1_2_text:

agenda_1: 
a1_1: 
a1_1_text: 
a1_2: 
a1_2_text:
```

Please help me organize this data better (probably by using objects here or maybe a JSON file?). I am essentially looking for a way to nest these as objects so it's more accessible at a later date. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think adding your folder structure, and how you organized the data above (are they in front matter of each template?) might give other more info to help!

Comment: Hi, thanks @KV88
I found the solution and I can see how my folder structure would've helped lol. Should I add the solution to my own question here? It's my first question here so I have no clue

Comment: Hi, yeah, I think if you have a question, others might have the same too, especially when the project gets a little more complicated. I think your solution would benefit others a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a separate data file, or putting it in the front-matter of each course, I would prefer to organize it like this in YAML:

```yaml
topics:
  - title: Topic Title 1
    subtopics:
      - title: Subtopic Title 1
        desc: Subtopic Description 1
      - title: Subtopic Title 2
        desc: Subtopic Description 2

  - title: Topic Title 2
    subtopics:
      - title: Subtopic Title 1
        desc: Subtopic Description 1
      - title: Subtopic Title 2
        desc: Subtopic Description 2
```